# Segmentation fault removal duplicate elements in unsorted linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, segmentation-fault

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

struct node{

    int data;
    struct node* next;

};

struct node* head;

void traversalLinkedList(struct node* ptr){

    if(ptr==NULL) {cout<<"null hain bhai"<<endl; return;}

    while(ptr!=NULL){
        cout<<ptr->data<<" ";
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }

}

void push(int d){

    //at the front of linked list

    struct node* temp=(struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    temp->data=d;
    temp->next=head;

    head=temp;

}


int main(){

    head=NULL;

  //removing duplicates from linked list

  push(10);
  push(11);
  push(12);
  push(11);
  push(11);
  push(12);
  push(10);

  traversalLinkedList(head);

  struct node *ptr;

  struct node* prev;

  struct node* qtr;

  for(ptr=head;ptr->next!=NULL;ptr=ptr->next){

    prev=ptr;

    for(qtr=ptr->next;qtr!=NULL;){


      if(ptr->data==qtr->data){
        //means duplicate nodes
        prev->next=qtr->next;
        free(qtr);
        qtr=prev->next;
      }

      else{
        prev=qtr;
        qtr=qtr->next;
      }



    }

  }

  cout<<endl;

  traversalLinkedList(head);

  cout<<endl;




    return 0;
}
```

I am not able to understand why I am getting segmentation fault for this code. This code is removal of duplicate elements from unsorted linked list.

***Explanation*** 
I am using a previous pointer to store the node previous to the inner loop pointer as soon as I find the inner loop node data is equal to outer loop node data, the previous pointer is made to point to inner loop node's next pointer and inner loop node is freed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```c
for(ptr=head;ptr->next!=NULL;ptr=ptr->next){
```

Should be

```c
for(ptr=head;ptr!=NULL;ptr=ptr->next){
```

It fails because at the end only two 12s are left and the ptr is pointing at one of them. It's next is not null so you enter the iteration. On that iteration you delete the second 12, so ptr's next now is null. Then the iteration ends, you set ptr to ptr->next, so ptr itself becomes null, then you check if ptr->next is null, and crash there.

Edit: if you want to skip the last element,  do

```c
for(ptr=head;ptr && ptr->next!=NULL;ptr=ptr->next){
```

Comment: `ptr && ptr->next!=NULL` is inconsistent; why not `ptr && ptr->next` (or `ptr != NULL && ptr->next != NULL`)? And it's quite pointless, since if `ptr->next` is NULL, the inner loop does nothing, so you might as well just test `ptr`.

Comment: I agree on consistency. Either of your suggestions is better. Regarding it being pointless, that's why at the beginning I suggest to just do ptr!=null. But the topic starter was saying in the comments that he wants to skip the last element

Comment: Well, the OP is confused ... the inner loop already avoids looking at the last item by starting with `qtr=ptr->next` rather than `qtr=ptr`. (And someone should tell him not to call it "qtr".)

Answer (score 2):

```
for(ptr=head;ptr->next!=NULL;ptr=ptr->next)
```

In this line when u say ptr->next!=NULL, a null pointer will be dereferenced for the last node. Which gives a segmentation fault because you are trying to access a null pointer.

So, just make the second condition as `ptr!=NULL`. That is enough as you are anyways doing `ptr=ptr->next` in your third condition of the `for` loop

Comment: I used that logic for having ptr->next!=NULL because i dont want the last node to be accessed as if it is a duplicate it would already have been removed. Can you please explain how the null pointer will be dereferenced for the last node and how come I am accessing null pointer using ptr->next!=NULL

Comment: @blankspace It has already been explained several times. Try tracing (with pencil and paper) through the code with a simple list (say, just two items with equal data) and see what it does. You will see not only that it crashes but that your "logic" makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

This condition `ptr->next!=NULL` in the for loop is problematic.

```
for(ptr=head;ptr->next!=NULL;ptr=ptr->next)
```

It will dereference `NULL`pointer for the last node. It should be :

```
for(ptr=head;ptr!=NULL;ptr=ptr->next)
```

Comment: I used that logic for having ptr->next!=NULL because i dont want the last node to be accessed as if it is a duplicate it would already have been removed. Can you please explain how the null pointer will be dereferenced for the last node

Comment: The increment statement in for loop is : 'ptr=ptr->next' . So if you are at the last node, in the next iteration ptr will be NULL. And the condition  check will be 'ptr->next!=NULL'. At this point ptr is NULL.

Comment: @GuillaumeGeorge There's no need for the extra condition and it achieves nothing over the correct `ptr!=NULL`. If ptr isn't NULL but ptr->next is, the inner loop is a noop.

Comment: @blankspace "Can you please explain how the null pointer will be dereferenced for the last node" -- `prev->next=qtr->next;` can set `prev->next` to NULL. Consider also that for an empty list (head == NULL) you immediately dereference NULL, which should tell you intuitively that it's wrong.